# Why isn't the graph of $y=|x|$ a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Consider the graph of $y=|x|$ from $-1<x<1$. Equip it with a single chart, the projection onto the $x$-axis. Is it now a smooth manifold? It seems like it shouldn't be smooth, but perhaps with only one chart, any manifold is smooth (because it trivially satisfies the compatibility condition)?

What chart could we put on there that would not be smoothly compatible with this first one?

Comment: It is a one-dimensional smooth manifold.

Comment: Think it this way, the "non smothness" of $y=|x|$ is on the way it is sitting in $\mathbb{R}^2$ not in the graph itself which is just $\mathbb{R}$.